# Weighted price in a data.frame with R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a weekly dataset  of prices of a product. This product has many varieties, each with its own price. I am interested in calculating a weighted price depending on the sales volume of each.

I tried to do with a loop, but does not work.

Can someone help me?

Here, a minimal example of my dataset:

Any

```
    nrow week variety        price volume
    1    10   Semiduro        911  15550
    2    10   Semiduro        809  13400
    3    10   Semiduro        611  15200
    4    10   Semiduro        517  17250
    5    10   Semiduro        389   4550
    6    10   Semiduro        300   1500
    7    10 Paisana(o)       1100  19200
    8    10 Paisana(o)        726  22900
    9    10 Paisana(o)        452  10450
    10   11   Semiduro       1362  13250
    11   11   Semiduro       1163   7100
    12   11   Semiduro       1032  15580
    13   11   Semiduro        768   9700
    14   11   Semiduro        703   3670
    15   11   Semiduro        550   1450
    16   11 Paisana(o)       1825  20200
    17   11 Paisana(o)       1402  30650
    18   11 Paisana(o)        838   9750
    19   12   Semiduro       1050  11350
    20   12   Semiduro        878   9200
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(week, variety) %>% 
   summarise(wprice = weighted.mean(price, volume))
#   week    variety    wprice
#  <int>      <chr>     <dbl>
#1    10 Paisana(o)  808.1598
#2    10   Semiduro  673.5663
#3    11 Paisana(o) 1452.2574
#4    11   Semiduro 1048.4625
#5    12   Semiduro  972.9976
```